# Can ADO.Net Entity Data Model validate unique field and display error message?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using ASP.Net with ADO.Net Entity Data Model. I use this for add record:

```
userEntity.AddToUSERs(newUser);
```

In this case, can ADO.Net Entity Data Model validate unique user and display error message?

Comment: What is unique? User Id? Is it `Guid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Entity Framework does not handle Unique Keys. You have to manually handle these cases.

One possible solution would be to catch the exception when `SaveChanges` is called and check the message of the `Exception` and extract which unique key is violated and then using that add a `ModelState` error with the relevant property name.

Comment: Which one is a good solution: 1. Handle exception, and 2. Check with database manually before insert?

Comment: @leapBun Handle the exception. Because the application is multi user, user name maybe occupied just after you check the availability.